# how to install and setup content Editor plugin in october cms?

Tags: octobercms

Can anyone please tell me or provide me video tutorial how to install and setup **Content Editor Plugin in October CMS**?

I have already tried searching for its tutorial in youtube but didnt found it. So ,i saw its documentation too but didn`t understand cause i am beginner to the October CMS. Here is the link of the content editor plugin https://octobercms.com/plugin/samuell-contenteditor

Please help me !!

Answer (score 0):

Check my below image for installation plugin step in **OctoberCMS** :

[image: Plugin Installation step 1]

[image: Plugin Installation step 2]

Comment: Thank you for the install process. can you please send me the setup process too? @Ashish Detroja

Comment: Please check plugins documents in below link https://octobercms.com/plugin/samuell-contenteditor

Comment: If you want to latest OctoberCMS setup visit below link https://octobercms.com/docs/setup/installation

Comment: Thank you for the links but i have already seen that links before .I was not able to understand cause i am a beginner . Here is my question which i didn`t understand in that links : 1) Check if you have {% framework %} and {% scripts %} inside layout for working ajax requests and {% styles %} for additional css? 2)Do we have to use ajax for this plugin? 3)Use this code in your page code and link the editor to a content file or set name to autocreate new file? @Ashish Detroja